# To show looping for two looping in random and cross

Tags: php, if-statement, for-loop

i have looping problem, i want To show replay random To looping

Code:

```html
            for ($i=0; $i <= 10; $i++) { 
            $result = $i;
            echo "$result";
            echo "<br>";
            }
    //----------------------------------------------
            echo "<hr width='100%'>";
    //----------------------------------------------
            $s=$result;
            $c=$result;
            $test=array_fill($s, $c, 0);
            $ts=microtime(true);

            for ($i=0; $i <= 10; $i++) { 
                $selection1=mt_rand($s, $c);
                $selection2=mt_rand($s, $c);

                echo "$selection1 and $selection1";
                echo "<br>";
            }
```

i want result:
[example result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OX21U.jpg)

and after random i want cross looping
[Example result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAmhj.jpg)

```
#including completion of a genetic algorithm
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: As it already got mentioned in your last question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37220786/3933332 `$result` will be 10 after your for loop has run. (BTW: quotes around your variable in the for loop are unnecessary). So after that you assign 10 to `$s` and `$c`. (In the meanwhile you create an array starting at the index 10 with 10 elements with the value 0). And in the next for loop you create random values between 10 and 10, and as random values are they are random. So mostly you will get 10!

Comment: I am still confused, if I want the results as above what I should do, please include examples of coding sir?

Answer (score 0):

`mt_rand` returns a value between the first and last values you provide.  In your code, you are calling `mt_rand($s, $c)` when $s and $c are both set to 10, so they will always return 10.

I'm having trouble understanding what you want, so let's take a look at your code and see what's going on.

```
        for ($i=0; $i <= 10; $i++) { 
            $result = $i;
            echo "$result";
            echo "<br>";
        }
```

Above we're looping between 0 and 10, each time around storing our loop number as `$result`.

```
//----------------------------------------------
        echo "<hr width='100%'>";
//----------------------------------------------
        $s=$result;
        $c=$result;
        $test=array_fill($s, $c, 0);
        $ts=microtime(true);
```

Our loop has finished and we're moving on.  This code is executed once.  Since `$result` was `10` at the end of the loop, `$s` and `$c` will always be set to 10.

```
        for ($i=0; $i <= 10; $i++) { 
            $selection1=mt_rand($s, $c);
            $selection2=mt_rand($s, $c);

            echo "$selection1 and $selection1";
            echo "<br>";
        }
```

We're now going to loop between 0 and 10 again.  `mt_rand()` will always return a value between `$s` and `$c`, which will always be set to `10` and `10`, so will always be `10`.  We're just going to echo `10 and 10` 10 times.

I'm unsure what you're looking for so I'll just leave that explanation there.

Comment: thanks to explanation,  
I am still confused, if I want the results as above what I should do, please include examples of coding sir? include your way please

Comment: how this set $ s and $ c so valued random, master or no other solution to this problem? with output as I want?

Comment: If you're having trouble understanding why `mt_rand()` is always outputting 10 after that explanation, you're probably trying to take on a challenge too difficult for your skill level.  This is a very simple problem.  If you need someone to write your code for you, consider hiring someone.